# Processing Java exe in a web page

Tags: java, html, web, exe

Back in 2010, I made a bunch of data visualization Java Applets using Processing1.  But then applets stopped working in our modern security world.  Processing2 came out, but I was not able to get my old code to work in JavaScript mode.  Now we have Processing3 that exports Java exe.  These runs just fine with my old Processing1 code, but I don't know what to do with them.  I am hoping it is a super easy question to answer, I just don't have a lot of HTML experience.
How do I get the Processing Java exe to run in a web page?
Is it the same as the old Java Applets?  Thanks.

Comment: A webpage doesn't run an executable.  You can offer the executable for *download* so that the *user* can run it on their computer.  (Basically, just link to the `.exe` file.)  Is that what you mean?

Comment: Bummer.  Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need [JavaScript version of the Processing package](http://processingjs.org/). From its QuickStart page:

> `Processing.js` is written in JavaScript, and uses HTML5's `<canvas>` element. It converts your Processing code to JavaScript and runs it.
>   Make your Processing `*.pde` files as you normally would, for example `hello-web.pde`.
>   Create a web page that includes `Processing.js` as well as a `<canvas>` with info about where to get your sketch file (you can specify multiple `*.pde` files, separating them with spaces):
>
> ```
> <script src="processing-1.0.0.min.js"></script>
> <canvas data-processing-sources="hello-web.pde"></canvas>
> ```
>
> Load your web page, and it will parse, translate, and run your sketch
>   in the browser.